# Point in time reqovery for just one schema or database

Tags: postgresql

I'm going to develop a multi-tenant application, where each tenant lives in its own database or schema (I've not decided this yet).

In this scenario, if I wanted to use point in time recovery (PITR), I also want to have it per-tenant. If a tenant has a problem, I want to be able to roll back only his database or schema and not the whole server.

While I found information how to do backup/restore in such situations with pg_dump and pg_restore, I haven't found any information for PITR.

Is this even possible? If yes, only per database or even per schema?

I can imagine that postgres maybe stores the log of the whole server in a single file, which may be the reason why it could not be possible. But I may be wrong..

Comment: this belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DanielA.White Is it possible to move the question there?

Comment: there is a close path or flag it.